# show/hide buttons on google map click

Tags: angularjs

I have google map with some cities marked. And each of this city has its own team. initially a button will be shown to the user stating "choose city".

How can i make it to hide when a user click on a marker and show another button with the city name on it?

so when the user clicks on it, a new page will appear with the team details

**HTML**

```
<section ng-app="mapsApp" ng-controller="MapsCtrl">
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <button>choose city </button>
  <button ng-click="teamname(team)">
  Your team is {{teamname}}
  </button>
  </div>

  <div id="map" class="col-md-8"></div>
</section>
```

**Javascript**

```
var cities = [{
  name: 'Toronto',
  team: 'Maple Leafs',
  lat: 43.643156,
  long: -79.379614
}, {
  name: 'New York',
  team: 'Rangers',
  lat: 40.750524,
  long: -73.993352
}, {
  name: 'Chicago',
  team: 'Blackhawks',
  lat: 41.881017,
  long: -87.674142
}, {
  name: 'Los Angeles',
  team: 'Kings',
  lat: 34.043076,
  long: -118.26701
}, {
  name: 'Boston',
  team: 'Bruins',
  lat: 42.365346,
  long: -71.062385
}, {
  name: 'Buffalo',
  team: 'Sabres',
  lat: 42.875036,
  long: -78.87611
}, {
  name: 'Detroit',
  team: 'Red Wings',
  lat: 42.325174,
  long: -83.051322
}, {
  name: 'Florida',
  team: 'Panthers',
  lat: 26.159598,
  long: -80.325469
}, {
  name: 'Montreal',
  team: 'Canadiens',
  lat: 45.496331,
  long: -73.570035
}, {
  name: 'Ottawa',
  team: 'Senators',
  lat: 43.251986,
  long: -79.806622
}, {
  name: 'Tampa Bay',
  team: 'Lightning',
  lat: 27.94274,
  long: -82.451709
}, {
  name: 'Carolina',
  team: 'Hurricanes',
  lat: 35.80344,
  long: -78.721894
}, {
  name: 'Columbus',
  team: 'Blue Jackets',
  lat: 39.969276,
  long: -83.006004
}, {
  name: 'New Jersey',
  team: 'Devils',
  lat: 40.733438,
  long: -74.171025
}, {
  name: 'New York',
  team: 'Islanders',
  lat: 40.722998,
  long: -73.590721
}, {
  name: 'Philadelphia',
  team: 'Flyers',
  lat: 39.901243,
  long: -75.171897
}, {
  name: 'Pittsburgh',
  team: 'Penguins',
  lat: 40.439174,
  long: -79.98972
}, {
  name: 'Washington',
  team: 'Capitals',
  lat: 38.898014,
  long: -77.020901
}, {
  name: 'Anaheim',
  team: 'Ducks',
  lat: 33.807804,
  long: -117.876481
}, {
  name: 'Calgary',
  team: 'Flames',
  lat: 51.037427,
  long: -114.051994
}, {
  name: 'Edmonton',
  team: 'Oilers',
  lat: 53.572174,
  long: -113.455192
}, {
  name: 'Phoenix',
  team: 'Coyotes',
  lat: 33.531987,
  long: -112.261158
}, {
  name: 'San Jose',
  team: 'Sharks',
  lat: 37.332802,
  long: -121.901171
}, {
  name: 'Vancouver',
  team: 'Canucks',
  lat: 49.277689,
  long: -123.108076
}, {
  name: 'Colorado',
  team: 'Avalanche',
  lat: 39.748955,
  long: -105.006341
}, {
  name: 'Dallas',
  team: 'Stars',
  lat: 32.790413,
  long: -96.810368
}, {
  name: 'Minnesota',
  team: 'Wild',
  lat: 44.944162,
  long: -93.100852
}, {
  name: 'Nashville',
  team: 'Predators',
  lat: 36.160036,
  long: -86.778542
}, {
  name: 'St. Louis',
  team: 'Blues',
  lat: 38.62646,
  long: -90.20207
}, {
  name: 'Winnipeg',
  team: 'Jets',
  lat: 49.892837,
  long: -97.14352
}];
/* End of Data  */

angular.module('mapsApp', [])
  .controller('MapsCtrl', function($scope) {

    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 4,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(45, -100),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

    $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

    $scope.cities = [];

    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var createMarker = function(city) {

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: $scope.map,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(city.lat, city.long),
      });
      marker.name = city.name;
      marker.team = city.team;

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent('<div class="infoWindowContent">' + marker.name + ' - ' + marker.team + '</div>');
        infoWindow.open($scope.map, marker);
      });

      $scope.cities.push(marker);

    }

    for (i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
      createMarker(cities[i]);
    }

    $scope.openInfoWindow = function(e, selectedMarker) {
      e.preventDefault();
      google.maps.event.trigger(selectedMarker, 'click');
    }

$scope.teamname = function (id) {
             $location.path('/team/'+id);

        };
  });
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Some fiddle would be useful, perhaps do you have one?

Comment: @Dario Yep... :) http://jsfiddle.net/h8512515/

Comment: something like this ? http://jsfiddle.net/h8512515/2/

Comment: @Dario.. Yep.. Thanks a lot.. How can make one button hidden when clicked?

Comment: <button ng-click="hide=true" ng-hide="hide">Click to hide me</button>

Comment: Got it working perfectly now :)